# How To Modify Object Property Via Property Name Index

Tags: typescript

I have this JSON file that I'm parsing using TypeScript.  After the JSON.prase, I need to lower case some values.  Everything is working fine when updating the properties via an integer index of an array, but when I use a property name string as an index of an object, the value is not updated in the parent object.

### Update: Added a Runnable Snippet

```js
function printFields(obj) {
  printLine(obj.stages[0].fieldScripts[0].preReq.field);
  printLine(obj.stages[0].fieldScripts[0].fields[0]);
  printLine(obj.stages[0].fieldScripts[0].optionalFields[0]);
}

function printLine(value) {
  document.body.innerHTML += value + "<br/>";
}

function fieldsToLowerCase(script) {
  forEachField({ in : script,
    action: function(field, i, fields) {
      fields[i] = field.toLowerCase();
    }
  });
}


function forEachField(info) {
  var forEachFieldInFields = function(fields) {
    if (!fields) {
      return;
    }

    fields.some(function(s) {
     
      printLine("Value before action: " + s.preReq.field);

      var breakHasBeenCalled = false;
      var breakableAction = function(f, i, array) {
        breakHasBeenCalled = info.action(f, i, array);
        return breakHasBeenCalled;
      };
      s.fields.some(breakableAction);
      if (breakHasBeenCalled) {
        return breakHasBeenCalled;
      }
      if (s.optionalFields) {
        s.optionalFields.some(breakableAction);
        return breakHasBeenCalled;
      }
      if (s.preReq) {
        var a = breakableAction(s.preReq.field, "field", s.preReq);
        printLine("Value after updated by Action: " + s.preReq.field);
        return a;
      }
      return breakHasBeenCalled;
    });
  };

  for (var _i = 0, _a = info.in.stages; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var stage = _a[_i];
    forEachFieldInFields(stage.fieldScripts);
  }
}


function getObject() {
  return {
    "stages": [{
      "stage": "Customer Info",
      "fieldScripts": [{
        "preReq": {
          "field": "Commercial",
          "value": "371060000"
        },
        "fields": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ],
        "optionalFields": [
          "middleName"
        ]
      }]
    }]
  };
}



var obj = getObject();
printFields(obj);

fieldsToLowerCase(obj);
printLine("");
printFields(obj);
```

Comment: That should work. Are you sure that `preReq` is not frozen?

Comment: @torazaburo, yes, thanks for the clarification.  I had a JSON file, and I did parse it into a JavaScript object, but before using it for business logic, I needed to update it.  I was just attempting to give a reason for why I am doing what I am doing.

Comment: @TamasHegedus frozen?  I haven't called freeze on anything if that's what you mean.

Comment: I don't see any trivial flaws in this code. You will either have to debug it yourself or provide a piece of code that we can run ourselves and reproduces your issue. I assume this code runs on node.

Comment: Thanks @TamasHegedus.  Providing a debug-able version for you helped me find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, once I added a runable script:

```
if (s.optionalFields) {
    s.optionalFields.some(breakableAction);
    return breakHasBeenCalled;
}
```

should look like

```
if (s.optionalFields) {
    s.optionalFields.some(breakableAction);
    if(breakHasBeenCalled){
        return breakHasBeenCalled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, didnt spot that